# закругленный треугольник before c одного угла

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, вёрстка

задача http://joxi.ru/BA0Lk9PCJYzpVA

> При закруглении одного угла получается не то,что хотелось бы.

```
.div:before {
   content: "";
   width: 0;
   height: 0;
   border: 12px solid;
   border-color: red transparent transparent red;
   position: absolute;
   left: 1px;
   bottom: -23px;
   border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 4px;
}
```

Comment: Не забывайте указывать что хотелось бы. Так же рекомендую формулировать заголовок таким образом, чтобы в конце можно было поставить вопросительный знак.

Comment: Спасибо за совет. Учту.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если "один в один", то CSS будет таким:

```css
body {
  background: #eee;
}

.tip {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  min-height: 227px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  margin: 0px auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}

.tip:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 189px;
  height: 144px;
  bottom: -72px;
  left: -1px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-left: 1px solid #aaa;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #aaa;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 44px;
  transform-origin: center center;
  transform: skewY(-37deg);
  background: linear-gradient(37deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="tip"></div>
```

Comment: Отлично , спасибо)

Answer (score 0):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<svg  viewBox="0 0 210 297" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <g transform="matrix(.56233 0 0 .53208 88.609 -19.878)">
  <path d="m-118.68 213.08c0.16461 21.419 0.32922 42.837 6.6278 43.091 6.2986 0.25345 18.731-20.658 31.163-41.57" fill="#fff" stroke="#000" stroke-width=".33883px"/>
  <path d="m-118.68 213.08-3e-3 -161.77 286.51 0.75595-1.5119 164.04-247.2-1.5074" fill="#fff" stroke="#000" stroke-width="0.2px"/>
  <text transform="scale(1.2956 .77182)" x="-22.754932" y="200.21956" fill="#000000" font-family="FontAwesome" font-size="75.577px" letter-spacing="0px" stroke-width="4.0488" word-spacing="0px" style="line-height:101.21985626px"><tspan x="-22.754932" y="200.21956" stroke-width="4"></tspan></text>
 </g>
</svg>
```